# Perlin Noise generating weird results

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation, perlin-noise

I'm coding an implementation of Perlin Noise in C#.
When I run the program it outputs this:

[image: Output:]

Every cell individually looks alright but when compared to it's neighbours they don't match.
(In some rare cases two or more cells do match each other).

This is the Perlin struct used for all the calculations:

```
 public struct Perlin
     {
 
         public struct _2D
         {
             public static float Simple(float x, float y, int seed)
             {
                 
                 Vector2 pos = new Vector2(x % 1, y % 1); // Position in the unit square
 
                 Vector2[] points = new Vector2[4];
                 points[0] = new Vector2(Mathf.Floor(x), Mathf.Floor(y)); // Corner positions
                 points[1] = new Vector2(Mathf.Floor(x), Mathf.Ceil(y)); // Corner positions
                 points[2] = new Vector2(Mathf.Ceil(x), Mathf.Ceil(y)); // Corner positions
                 points[3] = new Vector2(Mathf.Ceil(x), Mathf.Floor(y)); // Corner positions
 
 
                 Vector2[] vectorTable = new Vector2[] { new Vector2(-1, -1), new Vector2(1, -1), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(-1, 1) , new Vector2(Mathf.Sqrt(2), 0), new Vector2(0, Mathf.Sqrt(2)), new Vector2(-Mathf.Sqrt(2), 0), new Vector2(0, -Mathf.Sqrt(2)) };
 
                 Vector2[] gradients = new Vector2[4];
                 for (int g = 0; g < gradients.Length; g++)
                 {
                     gradients[g] = vectorTable[Mathf.RoundToInt(Random(new Vector2(points[g].x + seed, points[g].y + seed)) * (vectorTable.Length-1))]; // Gradient vector
                 }
 
 
                 Vector2[] directions = new Vector2[4];
                 for (int d = 0; d < directions.Length; d++)
                 {
                     directions[d] = (new Vector2(x - points[d].x, y - points[d].y) - pos).normalized; // Direction vector from the x and y position to the corner
                 }
 
                 float[] dots = new float[4];
                 for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
                 {
                     dots[i] = (Vector2.Dot(directions[i], gradients[i])); // Dot products
                 }
 
                 float lerp1 = (Mathf.Lerp(dots[0], dots[1], Fade(pos.y)));
                 float lerp2 = (Mathf.Lerp(dots[2], dots[3], Fade(pos.y)));
                 float lerp3 = (Mathf.Lerp(lerp1, lerp2, Fade(pos.x)));
 
 
                 
                 return (lerp3 + 1) / 2; // Remapping the output from (-1 to 1) to (0 to 1)
 
 
 
                 float Fade(float t)
                 {
                     return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10);
                 }
             }
        }
    }
```

And this is the Random() function:

```
static float Random(Vector2 seed)
     {
         Vector2 v1 = new Vector2(3.1251f, 17.8737f);
         float f1 = 43758.545312f;
         return fract(Mathf.Sin(Vector2.Dot(seed, v1) * f1)) ;
 
         float fract(float x)
         {
             return Mathf.Abs(x % 1.0f);
         }
     }
```

I tried to invert colors in some cells but it didn't create the expected result either.

Comment: What speaks against using [`Mathf.PerlinNoise`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PerlinNoise.html) ..?

Comment: @derHugo My final goal was to make a 3D version of perlin but first I wanted to get a 2D implementation working.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/938178/3d-perlin-noise.html , https://gist.github.com/tntmeijs/6a3b4587ff7d38a6fa63e13f9d0ac46d , among others  .. Don't reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for help but I've already tried those methods however they kept generating with artifacts. That was why I started making my own in the first place.